# Is there a way to create a custom FragmentTransaction for the back stack?

Tags: android

that is if I have a fragment and I want it to implement a custom operation when it's is removed from the back stack is there a way to override or implement something in a FragmentTransaction to enable the operation to take place when the entry is popped off the back stack -

Ie: maybe log something, or pop up a requester asking if you really want to or whatever.  It would seem sensible that the fragment itself should be able to define this operation and potentially either continue with or abort the "back a level" operation for itself when the user requests it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `FragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener()` with an `OnBackStackChangedListener` that checks the new back stack state and performs an operation based on the state.

Comment: I have an issue - I can get the top of stack entry and I can call getId() on it but when I try to find the fragment by ID it returns NULL - if I explicitly use the ID that the fragment was assigned in the resource file if is found.  How do I get it so the ID returned by the entry is the actual ID of the fragment the entry represents?

Comment: I call `addToBackStack()` with a specific name, then I call `getName()` on the `BackStackEntry` and compare it to that name to check if the stack is at a certain place.  Also for transaction `add()` and `replace()` I pass a String tag so I can call `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` to get the fragment later. So for example, if I call `transaction.add(R.id.container, detailFragment, "DetailFragment").addToBackStack("detail").commit()` then I compare back stack entry `getName()` to "detail", if equal then I can do `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("DetailFragment")`.

Comment: Yes thanks - I will set this as a answer.  But part of it is the ambiguity of the "crowd sourced" docs :)  The "tag" on the back stack entry is separate from the "tag" on the Fragment itself. find by tag finds the fragment based on it's tag.  It is only by manually specifying explicitly that tag in the back stack entry to be the tag in the Fragment that this works.  It does not default to the tag in the Fragment if not explicitly initialized.  Now I check if it is foned and if the fragment exhibits my "BackStackable" interface and calls that if present.